Adventure story involving island "Tombuktu"
My grandfather died more than 30 years ago, but before that he used to tell us countless stories.
One of them was an adventure story, involving a European (?) arriving on an island named "Tombuktu". I am well aware that my grandfather could have pronounced it wrongly, the "island" possibly being the city of Timbukty - and hopefully he did not confuse stories (or maybe the island was fictional).
He falls in love with the daughter of the chief of the people there (the character, not my grandfather), and she reciprocates. But other Europeans (?) come later and some stuff happens (I do not remember what). To save the situation, the chief of the people there adopts the main character (the 1st European), but now the European cannot marry the woman he loves, them now being brother and sister.
And I would like to read the original story, if I could ever find it.

This reminds me of favorite childhood book I read in Bulgarian:
"Остров Тамбукту" ("The Island of Tambuktu") by Марко Марчевски (Marko Marchevski). Looking at the goodreads.com record it was translated to Romanian, Armenian and Russian.
I have forgotten most of the plot but I searched the text online and it does appear to have that adoption detail:

— Не искам! — повторих аз думите на Смит и Стерн и прибавих: — Когато
спасих тана Боамбо от кадити, Зинга каза, че на големия празник ще
стане моя сахе. Но сега Арики отказа да ме осинови в своя род и аз
станах син на рода на тана Боамбо, а Зинга стана моя сестра…
— Така е! — прекъсна ме първожрецът. — Зинга стана твоя сестра и не
може да ти стане сахе. Но ти можеш да си вземеш жена от друг род.

Per Google Translate -

"I don't want to!" - I repeated the words of Smith and Stern, and added: - When I saved Thana Boambo from the Kadites, Zinga said that at the great feast he would become my sahe. But now Ariki refused to adopt me into his clan, and I became the son of thana Boambo's clan, and Zinga became my sister…
"That's right!" the high priest interrupted me. "Zinga has become your sister and she can't be your sahe." But you can take a wife of another race.


It looks plausible! Thanks! But that would be a challenge to find a readable version. I found something in Bulgarian (electronic, preferred), but I am not sure that an automatic translation would be good enough. And I have little hopes of finding the book on paper (not preferred).

I succeeded to finish reading a shoddy translation of the book, done by an online translator. This MUST be the book I was looking for. A lot of long lost details resurfaced to my mind while reading. You made me a happier person. Except for the bitter taste of the "liberty and freedom" at the end. I accept your answer as the correct answer.

Great! I remember next to nothing about the plot, and I think I'll not reread to keep the pink glow of childhood memory :)

I just had an idea: If you want to reinforce the "pink glow" (as I wanted), just read until close to the end, until something from "the outside" starts to be noticed from the island. And stop somewhere there.
